# How to do this xml elimination based on node attribute positions using XSLT ?

Tags: xml, xslt

Input file:

```
<root>
    <sector>
        <nodeA id="a">
            <section id="i">
                <item1 id="1" method="create"> 
                    <somechild>a</somechild>
                </item1>

                <item1 id="1" method="delete" />
            </section>                   
        </nodeA>

        <nodeA id="b">
            <cell id="ii">  
                <item2 id="2" method="create"> 
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </item2>
            </cell>
            <cell id="ii">
                <item2 id="2" method="delete" />
            </cell>                   
        </nodeA>

        <nodeB id="i">
            <cell id="ii">  
                <item3 id="1" method="create"> 
                    <child>b</child>
                </item3>
            </cell>

            <cell id="ii">
                <item3 id="1" method="delete" />
                <item3 id="1" method="create"> 
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </item3>
            </cell>                   
        </nodeB>
    </sector> 
</root>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<root>
    <sector>
        <nodeA id="a">
            <section id="i">
            </section>                   
        </nodeA>

        <nodeA id="b">
            <cell id="ii">  
            </cell>
            <cell id="ii">
            </cell>                   
        </nodeA>

        <nodeB id="i">
            <cell id="ii">  
                <item3 id="1" method="create"> <!-- this is not eliminated as it violates the rule by having create followed by delete and followed by create again -->
                    <child>b</child>
                </item3>
            </cell>

            <cell id="ii">
                <item3 id="1" method="delete" />
                <item3 id="1" method="create"> 
                    <otherchild>a</otherchild>
                </item3>
            </cell>                   
        </nodeB>
    </sector> 
</root>
```

I need to eliminate node in xml using this rule:

- one node with `method="create"` followed with one node with `method="delete"` will be eliminated
- the scenario can happen in one parent or spread in two parent as long as it has the same element name and id `<cell id="ii">`

How can I do this transformation using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Thank you.

Comment: Can it be that you keep asking the same question over and over again, effectively letting SO users do your work? All [your previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1336019/john?tab=questions) look and feel the same and yet you keep coming up with new ones that are just like the others. You have received long and complete answers to your other questions, but I have the feeling that you just copy the code, ignore the explanations and simply post another question if you need to get something done. Sorry, this isn't how this site works.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm sorry if you feel that way. It's just that I'm implementing those case to work with my xml structure as I cannot post the real file here. That is why I have to make an analogy,and when I put the files together it doesn't work and I have to change the questions, which resulted on posting similar question but actually has different algorithm on it.

Comment: In your XSLT you have a comment saying `this is not eliminated as it violates the rule by having create followed by delete and followed by create again` but I can't see how this relates to the rule you have specified in the question. You have one node with `method="create"` and one node with `method="delete"` and so shouldn't it be deleted? Could you elaborate on this rule a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC as you can see after the `<method="delete">` it is followed again by `<method="create">`, so it become `create\delete\create` where as the rule is for one create and one delete only (create\delete). I hope that clears out the confusion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach. You define a key to group your items you are looking to remove. I think you are grouping by the @id attribute of the element, together with the @id attribute of the two parent nodes

```
<xsl:key 
   name="items" 
   match="*[@method != '']" use="concat(@id, '|', ../@id, '|', ../../@id)" />
```

Next, you could have a template to match your **@method='create'** items where there are two elements in the key, and the other item is a **@method='delete'**

```
<xsl:template match="*
   [@method = 'create']
   [count(key('items', concat(@id, '|', ../@id, '|', ../../@id))) = 2]
   [key('items', concat(@id, '|', ../@id, '|', ../../@id))[@method = 'delete']]" />
```

You would also need a template to match the other **@method='delete'** in a similar manner.

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="items" match="*[@method != '']" use="concat(@id, '|', ../@id, '|', ../../@id)" />

   <xsl:template match="*[@method = 'create'][count(key('items', concat(@id, '|', ../@id, '|', ../../@id))) = 2][key('items', concat(@id, '|', ../@id, '|', ../../@id))[@method = 'delete']]" />
   <xsl:template match="*[@method = 'delete'][count(key('items', concat(@id, '|', ../@id, '|', ../../@id))) = 2][key('items', concat(@id, '|', ../@id, '|', ../../@id))[@method = 'create']]" />

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<root>
   <sector>
      <nodeA id="a">
         <section id="i"/>
      </nodeA>
      <nodeA id="b">
         <cell id="ii"/>
         <cell id="ii"/>
      </nodeA>
      <nodeB id="i">
         <cell id="ii">
            <item3 id="1" method="create">
               <child>b</child>
            </item3>
         </cell>
         <cell id="ii">
            <item3 id="1" method="delete"/>
            <item3 id="1" method="create">
               <otherchild>a</otherchild>
            </item3>
         </cell>
      </nodeB>
   </sector>
</root>
```